# (Sharepoint 2010 ) After "Remove Solution", when tried to Reinstall the error "failed to extract the cab....."

Tags: sharepoint, installation, uninstallation, wsp

Well, I had an issue with a custom Webpart, and nothing works. Then I had the brilliant idea of uninstall the solution, and try to reinstall (QA), because in Desenv and in my local machine the WSP works well

When I removed the solution by the "Central Administration/System Settings/Manage Farm Solutions" and tried to reinstall the same WSP, I take the error "failed to extract the cab file......" in the Sharepoint Managment Shell.

Thank you guys.

Comment: Try resetting the SharePoint services (Administration, Timer Service).

Comment: I already restart the machine, it would serve as reset? Because I can't find the Timer Service, and it's not fixed

Comment: Done, and nothing =(